# mongodb installation Windows 10 issue

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have installed MongoDB and run the mongod.exe. Please find below screenhot:

[mongod.exe execution -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqfGF.png)

I am trying to run the mongo.exe but > symbol is not coming to write command. Please see screenshot.
[mongo.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMqTu.png)

Please suggest.

Comment: Firewall isn't blocking it?